# Have Ant-Man's terrifying powers been explored by the authors before?

Tags: marvel, comics, ant-man

In my mind, the scariest and probably the most powerful hero is probably Ant-Man.

One of the reasons would be that he can shrink to microscopic size, enter through your skin, and then *grow* again inside his victims exploding them as if it's a *Mortal Kombat* finisher move.

Another would be that he can travel through his victim's heart and punch it. One of the most terrifying facts about this is that while his size is that small, the force that his punches give is still as if he were at normal size (due to the nature of Pym Particles as explained in the movie).

However, was there ever a comic where the authors have explored this ability of Ant-Man? When would this not work? Is there a reason why Hank Pym or other iterations of Ant-Man avoid doing this?

Comment: For most superheroes killing people is laughably easy.  Apprehending a villian without killing them or wrecking a large swath of the city is usually the problem.  Ant-Man pinching closed one of the main coronal arteries would stop human villains pretty quickly without killing them but it would make for pretty boring stories.

Comment: He can't go inside skin without activating the main belt button (and then, returning would be impossible). Normally, he can shrink to normal insect size. If he tried to enter using nose, he'll be sniffed out of the body.

Comment: Also, he can't kill Hulk no matter what he does.

Comment: It just requires a Spider-Man to knock him down.

Comment: “Is there a reason why Hank Pym or other iterations of Ant-Man avoid doing this?” Because it’s murder, and they’re heroes?

Comment: I believe Ultimate Wasp once crawled inside Hulk's head to deliver a shock to his brain (to subdue, rather than kill), but the only terrifying uses for Ant-Man's powers that I recall was that one issue where he shrunk down for sexual purposes with a full-sized Wasp (the hero, not the insect, which would probably be even more terrifying).

Answer (score 6):

In one issue of West Coast Avengers (late 80s, early 90s?) they were attacked by a (fake) Ultron.  Pym shrank Wonder Man down to insect size, and when he re-enlarged he destroyed the Ultron body.  It was during the period when Pym was referring to himself as 'Dr Pym, Scientific Adventurer' and was not using the Pym Particles on himself, only on non-living items (and weird edge cases like Wonder Man, who is solidified energy if I recall correctly).