# Why doesn't Dr. Strange fight by opening portals in front of moving body parts and severing them

Tags: marvel

I don't care about Thanos, nor the MCU only. I don't know if Strange can open and close portals in the comics, but I only want to know why he as a character doesn't use them to fight.

Why doesn't Dr. Strange fight people by opening portals in front of moving body parts (punched fists, running legs, jumping heads) and then closing the portals?

It seems to me this would be so efficient, what can the bad guys do?

When someone is distracted, quick, open portal below him, he falls halfway through, close portal. Why doesn't Strange do this more often?

Why is this not something he practises?

Comment: Think this has been asked before.

Comment: kinda - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186722/why-doesnt-doctor-strange-remove-the-infinity-gauntlet-from-thanos

Comment: and - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88474/why-didnt-dr-strange-create-a-portal-to-cut-off-thanos-hand

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88506/why-doesnt-dr-strange-fight-by-opening-portals-in-front-of-moving-body-parts-a

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Doctor Strange remove the Infinity Gauntlet from Thanos?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186722/why-doesnt-doctor-strange-remove-the-infinity-gauntlet-from-thanos)

Comment: I think you're confusing Dr. Strange with Conan. Presumably, Dr. Strange would prefer not to kill or maim his opponents, if possible.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The other question asks why Doctor Strange doesn't use this form of attack on *Thanos* in particular, and the reasons suggested are tied pretty specifically to Thanos, and the attack on him in particular. This appears to be asking about why doesn't Dr. Strange use this as a normal form of attack against opponents in general; the reasons not to use it against Thanos don't necessarily apply to other opponents.

Comment: @RDFozz No matter how high his moral high ground is, I'd like to think he could put it aside for a single moment to cut off someone's hand for the sake of the fate of half the universe.

Comment: @SydneySleeper - Note: this question isn't talking about *Thanos* as an opponent; it's asking why this isn't a standard fighting tactic Dr. Strange would employ. I'd agree that the tactic would seem logical in the specific circumstance you state - much less so if he's trying to stop a pickpocket.

Comment: @RDFozz Ah, well in that case you'd be right then. I agree, portal-severing the arm of a pickpocket would be just a slight overreaction

Answer (score 4):

Two reasons.

- **Time.** It takes a nontrivial amount of time to open and close a portal. If I recall correctly, in *Infinity War* there's a scene in which Wong communicates to Dr. Strange through a portal (by nodding his approval) *while it's closing*. In combat, a second can be an eternity-- portals simply don't open or close fast enough to be used as an offensive weapon like this.
  (There's also a scene in *Infinity War* in which

  > an enemy actually *does* have his hand severed by a portal closing, but it wasn't Strange's intent to do so.)
- **Intent.** Severing a limb is a very permanent and not-easily-undone measure, and severing someone at the torso could easily be fatal. As the first comment to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158634/have-ant-mans-terrifying-powers-been-explored-by-the-authors-before) points out, killing someone is, for most superheroes, laughably easy and the challenge is often finding a way of defeating an enemy *without* killing them. This is even more true for Dr. Strange, with his reality-altering magic. Even if he could learn how to use his portals this way, he might not even want to.